# How to fill control to whole free space in ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to fill my control to whole place in `ListViewItem`. For example I put `StackPanel(horizontalAlignment=Right)` and textBlock in it, I want to show text at right of column.But for this reason it seems center of column. Tried several things but couldn't solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the property [HorizontalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx) of the actual ListView to `Stretch`.

This will force the item template to go full width, instead of minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
<ListView >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListViewItem>
                <TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel},Path=ActualWidth}" TextAlignment="Right">ABC</TextBlock>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
```